# WinForms. Ширина ListBox

Tags: c#, winforms

Хочу в окошке создать ListBox, но есть проблемы с размерами. Мне нужно, чтобы ListBox занимал всю ширину окошка, а по краям был маленький отступ (например, 5 пикселей).

Сейчас это выглядит вот так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А должно быть так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Не могу понять, почему сейчас ширина ListBox'а больше чем ширина окна

```
var tv = new ListBox();
tv.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(5, 5);
tv.Width = 290;

tv.Items.Add("Window width: " + Width);
tv.Items.Add("LB width: " + tv.Width);

Controls.Add(tv);
```

Comment: выставь вручную размер как тебе нужно визуально, а потом настрой алигмент в вижуал студио в настройках контрола

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.dock?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: По-моему у окна 4 пикселя лишний отступ с каждой стороны есть, когда запущенное приложение. Или 8, которые компенсируются при развороте окна на весь экран.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно задать padding родительскому контролу, на который помещён листбокс:

```
this.Padding = new Padding(5);

var listBox = new ListBox
{
    Parent = this,
    Dock = DockStyle.Top,
    Height = 150
};
```

Если наличие паддинга будет мешать размещению других контролов, то листбокс следует поместить на панель с паддингом, а саму панель на родительский контрол без паддинга.

---

Класс [SystemInformation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.systeminformation?view=net-5.0) содержит информацию о размерах бордюров, рамок и т. п. Их всегда нужно учитывать при ручном задании размеров контролов. Но лучше использовать автоматический layout: задавать padding и margin, использовать TableLayoutPanel, FlowLayoutPanel и тому подобные возможности.

[Position and layout of controls](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/controls/layout?view=netdesktop-5.0)
[Layout in Windows Forms Controls](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/controls/layout-in-windows-forms-controls?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8)